# codesnippets not showing correctly in VS 2015 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

While developing on c# projects the installed Visual-C# snippets (like ctor, prop, ..) don't work any more in Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2.

When pressing <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> instead of showing all snippets (including Visual-C# snippets) I only get default snippets for ASP.NET MVC 4:

```
mvcaction4 and mvcpostaction4
```

I have tried resetting the environment (tools`->`import and export settings) and also: `devenv /resetuserdata`.

CodeSnippet manager shows all code snippets, the files are there correctly
(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1031\Visual C#`)

It seems as if visual studio doesn't recognize the project environment (C#) anymore.

Rest of Intellisense is working correctly, just not showing the right code snippets.

**UPDATE**: Installation repair and a complete uninstall and new install of visual studio 2015 Update 2 didn't help.

Comment: Workaround solution: In CodeSnippet Manager I imported all code snippets from the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1031\Visual C# into the folder: "My Code Snippets". Then they appear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved after updating to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.